# How to extract 3rd element from a JSON array in Jmeter

Tags: arrays, json, regex, jmeter

I need to extract the 3rd time element of the below JSON array.

```
[
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": " How to Shape of Character Design",
        "write": "Jun Bale",
        "date": "20/12/20",
        "time": "10:00AM",
        "body": " Because he takes  nsuscipit accepted result lightly with  nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire  nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely ",
        "image": "https://source.unsplash.com/rDEOVtE7vOs/1600x900",
        "tag": ["good", "great", "javascript", "wife"]
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "write": "Henry Cavil",
        "
date": "21/12/20",
        "time": "08:00AM",
        "title": " How to Write About Your Life? Start Here .",
        "body": " it is the time of  nseq are not criticize consumer happy that the pain or  nfugiat soothing pleasure forward or no discomfort may rejecting some  nWho, not being due, we may be able to open the man who did not, but there is no ",
        "image": "https://source.unsplash.com/WNoLnJo7tS8/1600x900",
        "tag": ["happy", "USA", "no", "wife"]
    },
    {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "write": "Katrina Tayl,
    "date": "24/12/20",
        "time": "06:49PM",
        "title": " How to Survive as a Freelancer in 2020 ",
        "body": " innocent, but the law  nvoluptatis blinded the election or the  nvoluptatis pains or prosecutors who is to pay nmolestiae and is willing to further or to and from the toil of an odious term ",
        "image": "https://source.unsplash.com/vMV6r4VRhJ8/1600x900",
        "tag": ["indian", "babbyes", "java", "hate"]
    }
]
```

I tried extracting via JSON extractor using -- `$..time[2]` & `$..['time'][2]` but no avail. I get an empty array. When I try using `$..time` I get 3 values

```
[
   "10:00AM",
   "08:00AM",
   "06:49PM"
]
```

But I only want the 3rd item, i.e., 06:49PM. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `arr[2].time` ?

Comment: There is no array name called "arr"

Comment: ohh sorry, I was referring to your JSON array. Did you somehow store it inside a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want solution in [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) it would be something like:

```
[2].time
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Introduction to JsonPath](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath)
- [JsonPath Examples](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#path-examples)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a formatting issue in the JSON.
It was corrected.

```
[
   {
      "userId":1,
      "id":1,
      "title":" How to Shape of Character Design",
      "write":"Jun Bale",
      "date":"20/12/20",
      "time":"10:00AM",
      "body":" Because he takes  nsuscipit accepted result lightly with  nreprehenderit discomfort may be the entire  nnostrum of the things that happens is that they are extremely ",
      "image":"https://source.unsplash.com/rDEOVtE7vOs/1600x900",
      "tag":[
         "good",
         "great",
         "javascript",
         "wife"
      ]
   },
   {
      "userId":1,
      "id":2,
      "write":"Henry Cavil",
      "date":"21/12/20",
      "time":"08:00AM",
      "title":" How to Write About Your Life? Start Here .",
      "body":" it is the time of  nseq are not criticize consumer happy that the pain or  nfugiat soothing pleasure forward or no discomfort may rejecting some  nWho, not being due, we may be able to open the man who did not, but there is no ",
      "image":"https://source.unsplash.com/WNoLnJo7tS8/1600x900",
      "tag":[
         "happy",
         "USA",
         "no",
         "wife"
      ]
   },
   {
      "userId":1,
      "id":3,
      "write":"Katrina Tayl",
      "date":"24/12/20",
      "time":"06:49PM",
      "title":" How to Survive as a Freelancer in 2020 ",
      "body":" innocent, but the law  nvoluptatis blinded the election or the  nvoluptatis pains or prosecutors who is to pay nmolestiae and is willing to further or to and from the toil of an odious term ",
      "image":"https://source.unsplash.com/vMV6r4VRhJ8/1600x900",
      "tag":[
         "indian",
         "babbyes",
         "java",
         "hate"
      ]
   }
]
```

It is possible to extract the specific index with the match number setting in the [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this,

> *$..[2]["time"]*  or  *$..[2].time*

For example: if I have a simple array,

> *arr=["A","B","C","D"];*

and I want to print *"C"* from *"arr"*. Then it will be use

> *arr[2];// result: C; starting index = 0*

again if I have an array

> *arr2=[{"x":"A","y":"B"},{"x":"C","y":"D"},{"x":"E","y":"F"}];*

and I want to print *"C"* from *"arr2"*. Then it will be

> *arr2[1]// result: {"x":"C","y","D"}*
>
> *arr2[1]["x"]// result: C*